# Crank-Nicolson in 1d time-dependent and nonlinear Fokker-Planck doesn't conserve mass

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-differential-equations, finite-differences

I'm making a Python implementation of the Crank-Nicolson method to solve a nonlinear time-dependent Fokker-Planck equation:

$\partial_t \rho = -(F \partial_x \rho +\rho \partial_x F)  +\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\partial^2_{x}\rho$

However the "mass" (the probability) is not being conserved when $\partial_xF$ is not $0$.

My scheme is the following:
I'm considering a scheme with Considering a grid $x={x_0,.\dots,x_J}$ and a time steps $t={t_0,\dots,t_N}$, using central differences in space and forward difference in time, we get
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
  \partial_t \rho &= \frac{\rho^{n+1}_{j}-\rho^{n}_{j}}{\Delta t}\\
  F \partial_x \rho &= \beta F^{n+1}_{j}\frac{\rho^{n+1}_{j+1}-\rho^{n+1}_{j-1}}{2\Delta x}+(1-\beta)F^{n}_{j}\frac{\rho^{n}_{j+1}-\rho^{n}_{j-1}}{2\Delta x}\\
  \rho \partial_x F &= \beta\rho^{n+1}_{j}\frac{F^{n+1}_{j+1}-F^{n+1}_{j-1}}{2\Delta x}+(1-\beta)\rho^{n}_{j}\frac{F^{n}_{j+1}-F^{n}_{j-1}}{2\Delta x}\\
  \partial^2_x \rho &= \beta\frac{\rho^{n+1}_{j+1}-2\rho^{n+1}_{j}+\rho^{n+1}_{j-1}}{2\Delta x^2}+(1-\beta)\frac{\rho^{n}_{j+1}-2\rho^{n}_{j}+\rho^{n}_{j-1}}{2\Delta x^2}
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
The C-N scheme usually has $\beta=0.5$. In our case, $\beta=0$ recovers the forward scheme, and $\beta=1$ the implicit backwards scheme.

Defining
$D=\frac{\sigma^2}{2}$,  $\xi=\frac{D}{\Delta x}$, $\delta_c=\frac{\Delta t}{2\Delta x}$, and putting all together:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
\rho^{n+1}_{j}-\rho^{n+1}_{j} &= - [\beta \delta_c F^{n+1}_{j} (\rho^{n+1}_{j+1}-\rho^{n+1}_{j-1})+(1-\beta)\delta_c F^{n}_{j} (\rho^{n}_{j+1}-\rho^{n}_{j-1})]\\
&-[\beta\delta_c\rho^{n+1}_{j}(F^{n+1}_{j+1}-F^{n+1}_{j-1})+(1-\beta)\delta_c\rho^{n}_{j}(F^{n}_{j+1}-F^{n}_{j-1})] \\
&+\xi\delta_c\beta(\rho^{n+1}_{j+1}-2\rho^{n+1}_{j}+\rho^{n+1}_{j-1})+\xi\delta_c(1-\beta)(\rho^{n}_{j+1}-2\rho^{n}_{j}+\rho^{n}_{j-1})
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Separating $\rho^n$ and $\rho^{n+1}$
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
  \rho^{n+1}_{j} &+ \beta \delta_c F^{n+1}_{j} (\rho^{n+1}_{j+1}-F^{n+1}_{j-1})+\beta\delta_c\rho^{n+1}_{j}(F^{n+1}_{j+1}-F^{n+1}_{j-1})-\xi\delta_c\beta(\rho^{n+1}_{j+1}2\rho^{n+1}_{j}+\rho^{n+1}_{j-1}) =\\
  &\rho^{n}_{j}-(1-\beta)\delta_c F^{n}_{j}(\rho^{n}_{j+1}-\rho^{n}_{j-1})
  -(1-\beta)\delta_c\rho^{n}_{j}(F^{n}_{j+1}-F^{n}_{j-1})
  +\xi\delta_c(1-\beta)(\rho^{n}_{j+1}-2\rho^{n}_{j}+\rho^{n+1}_{j-1})
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Then the scheme can be written as
\begin{equation}
  A \rho^{n+1}_{j}= B\rho^{n}_{j}
\end{equation}

where
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
 A &= I + \delta_c\beta A_{\mathrm{advection}}- \xi\delta_c\beta A_{\mathrm{difussion}}\\
 B &=I - \delta_c(1-\beta) A_{\mathrm{advection}}+ \xi\delta_c(1-\beta) A_{\mathrm{difussion}}\\
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

with
\begin{equation}
A_{\mathrm{advection}}=\begin{bmatrix}
 F^{n+1}_{2}-F^{n+1}_{0} & F^{n+1}_{1} & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
 -F^{n+1}_{1} & F^{n+1}_{3}-F^{n+1}_{1} & F^{n+1}_{2} & \dots & 0 \\
 0 & -F^{n+1}_{2} & F^{n+1}_{4}-F^{n+1}_{2} & \dots & 0 \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & F^{n+1}_{J+1}-F^{n+1}_{J-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

where $F^{n+1}_{0}$ and $F^{n+1}_{J+1}$ have to be chosen as a boundary condition, since it's outside the array.
$B_{\mathrm{advection}}$ is the same as $A_{\mathrm{advection}}$ at time step $n$.

The diffusion matrices are:
\begin{equation}
 A_{\mathrm{difussion}}=B_{\mathrm{difussion}}=\begin{bmatrix}
  -2 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
  1 & -2 & 1 & \dots & 0 \\
  0 & 1 &-2 & \dots & 0 \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & -2
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Therefore

\begin{equation}
 A=\begin{bmatrix}
  1+\delta_c\beta(F^{n+1}_{2}-F^{n+1}_{0}+2\xi) & \delta_c\beta(F^{n+1}_{1}-\xi) & 0 & \dots  \\
  \delta_c\beta(-F^{n+1}_{1}-\xi) & 1+\delta_c\beta(F^{n+1}_{3}-F^{n+1}_{1}+2\xi) & \delta_c\beta(F^{n+1}_{2}-\xi) & \dots \\
  0 & \delta_c\beta(-F^{n+1}_{2}-\xi) & 1+\delta_c\beta(F^{n+1}_{4}-F^{n+1}_{2}+2\xi) & \dots  \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & \dots 
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 B=\begin{bmatrix}
  1-\delta_c(1-\beta)(F^{n}_{2}-F^{n}_{0}+2\xi) & -\delta_c(1-\beta)(F^{n}_{1}-\xi) & 0 & \dots \\
  -\delta_c(1-\beta)(-F^{n}_{1}-\xi) & 1-\delta_c(1-\beta)(F^{n}_{3}-F^{n}_{1}+2\xi) & -\delta_c(1-\beta)(F^{n}_{2}-\xi) & \dots  \\
  0 & -\delta_c(1-\beta)(-F^{n}_{2}-\xi) & 1-\delta_c(1-\beta)(F^{n}_{4}-F^{n}_{2}+2\xi) & \dots  \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & \dots 
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

The integration scheme needs to solve $\rho^{n+1}_{j}= A^{-1}B\rho^{n}_{j}$.

I'm using some Neumann boundary conditions such that the derivative at x[0],x[N] is the same as that at x[1],x[N-1].

I'm using the following code:

```
from __future__ import division
from scipy.sparse import spdiags
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve
import numpy as np
import pylab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.close('all')

def F_OB(x,t,v=-2,x0=0):    "Ornstein uhlembeck field"
    FM=np.zeros([len(x),len(t)])
    FM=[v*(x-x0) for i in range(len(t))]
    return FM

def F_drift(x,t,v=-2):    "Constant drift field"
    FM=np.zeros([len(x),len(t)])
    FM=[np.array(v*np.ones(len(x)),dtype='float64') for i in range(len(t))]
    return FM

def F_cos(x,t,v=0.01): "periodic forcing drift field"
    FM=np.zeros([len(x),len(t)]) 
    FM=[v*np.cos(t[i])*np.array(v*np.ones(len(x)),dtype='float64') for i in range(len(t))]
    return FM
```

```
def makeCN_advection_difussion_matrices(x, dc,xi,FM,FM1,beta=0.5):    
    temp_F=np.zeros(len(x)) #gotta implement time evolution.
    temp_F=[1*(FM[i+1]-FM[i-1]) for i in range(1,len(x)-1)]
    Fn_diag=np.copy(FM)

    Fn_diag[0]=2*(FM[1]-FM[0])
    Fn_diag[-1]=2*(FM[-1]-FM[-2])
    Fn_diag[1:-1]=temp_F
    temp_F=[1*(FM1[i+1]-FM1[i-1]) for i in range(1,len(x)-1)]
    Fn1_diag=np.copy(FM)
    
    Fn1_diag[1:-1]=temp_F
    Fn1_diag[0]=2*(FM1[1]-FM1[0])
    Fn1_diag[-1]=2*(FM1[-1]-FM1[-2])
    
    ones = np.ones(len(x))
    Aid = spdiags( [ones], (0), len(x), len(x) )
    Aadv = spdiags( [-FM1, Fn1_diag, FM1], (-1,0,1), len(x), len(x) )
    Adif = spdiags( [ones, -2*ones, ones], (-1,0,1), len(x), len(x) )
    
    A = Aid.tocsr() + beta*dc*Aadv.tocsr() - beta*xi*dc*Adif.tocsr()
    
    Mid = spdiags( [ones], (0), len(x), len(x) )
    Madv = spdiags( [-FM, Fn_diag, FM], (-1,0,1), len(x), len(x) )
    Mdif = spdiags( [ones, -2*ones, ones], (-1,0,1), len(x), len(x) )
    
    M = Mid.tocsr() - (1-beta)*dc*Madv.tocsr() + (1-beta)*xi*dc*Mdif.tocsr()
    return A, M


s=0.1 # Set up basic constants
J = 3000 # total number of mesh points
xmin=-13
dt = 0.1    # time step

x = np.linspace(xmin,-xmin,J) # vertices
dx = np.abs(x[1]-x[0]) # space step
tf=100+dt#300
t=np.arange(0,tf,dt) 
tp=t[:-2]

FM=F_OB(x,t,v=-0.01,x0=0) # FM=F_drift(x,t,v=0.1) # FM=F_cos(x,t,v=1) 

dc=0.5*dt/dx
xi=0.5*s**2/dx


def Rinit2(x,mean, cov): #### Initial conditions (peak function)
    from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
    # pos = np.dstack((x))
    return multivariate_normal.pdf(x, mean, cov)

s0=s/3 
pdf = Rinit2(x,mean=-0.5,cov=s0)
p0 = pdf
print('integral check: ', np.trapz(p0,x))
u_init = p0


A, M = makeCN_advection_difussion_matrices(x, dc,xi,FM[0],FM[1],beta=0.5) #Integration scheme
u = u_init
u[0]=u[1]+u[2]-u[3];u[-1]=u[-2]-u[-4]+u[-3]#Newmann boundary, the derivative is te same as the previuos or next point
ut=np.zeros([np.shape(u)[0],len(tp)])
ut[:,0]=u
for i in range(len(tp)):
    u = spsolve(A, M * u)
    u[0]=u[1]+u[2]-u[3];u[-1]=u[-2]-u[-4]+u[-3]#Newmann boundary, the derivative is te same as the previuos or next point
    ut[:,i]=u
    A, M = makeCN_advection_difussion_matrices(x, dc,xi,FM[i],FM[i+1],beta=0.5)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolor(tp,x,ut)
ax.set_ylim([x[0],x[-1]])

mass=[np.trapz(ut[:,i],x) for i in range(len(tp))]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(tp,mass)

from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(x, ut[:,0],color='C0')
def update(i):
    line.set_ydata(ut[:,i])
    return (line)
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=range(len(tp)), interval=40)
```

It works fine for pure diffusion, pure advection, and constant advection with diffusion. But in the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck case the probability grows exponentially.